# cordova script src takes relative path rather absolute

Tags: javascript, cordova, phonegap-build, hybrid-mobile-app, cordova-cli

I am building a hybrid app out of cordova . my folder structure looks like

---

www

- bower_components
- components
- fonts
- scripts
- styles
- images

index.html

---

When i build the project using cordova (**cordova build**) and when i run **cordova serve**
the javascripts files are served from root path 
[image]Javascript takes from relative path whereas the css are loaded perfectly

Please help me in solving this is issue. but this is not problem when i run demo project from cordova .

this is index file. its in minified version

```html
<!doctype html> <html class="no-js"> <head> <meta charset="utf-8"> <title>KnoTalk</title> <meta name="description" content=""> <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"> <!-- Place favicon.ico and apple-touch-icon.png in the root directory --> <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/vendor.460a10c2.css"> <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/main.b59cb9a9.css"> <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="images/favicon.fcf321eb.png"> <base href="/">  <body ng-app="knotalk"> <div class="sidebar sidebar-left"> <div ng-include="'components/sidebar/sidebar.html'"></div> </div> <div class="sidebar sidebar-right"> <div ng-controller="MainController"> <div ng-if="isChannel"> <div ng-include="'components/middleSection/channelMetaInfo.html'"></div> </div> <div ng-if="!isChannel"> <div ng-include="'components/middleSection/userMetaInfo.html'"></div> </div> </div> </div> <div class="app" ng-swipe-right="Ui.turnOn(&quot;uiSidebarLeft&quot;)" ng-swipe-left="Ui.turnOff(&quot;uiSidebarLeft&quot;)"> <!-- Add your site or application content here --> <!-- angular spinner --> <span us-spinner spinner-key="spinner-1"></span> <div ng-include="src='components/header/header.html'"></div> <div class="app-body"> <div class="app-content"> <div ng-view=""></div> </div> </div> </div> <div ui-yield-to="modals"></div> <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="scripts/oldieshim.fa8ddb71.js"></script>
    <![endif]--> <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" href="scripts/vendor.1a204611.js"></script> <script href="scripts/scripts.79913f18.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

`

Comment: It'll be better if you can show the css & js script adding codes

Comment: i have added the index.html file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was not with cordova its because i have added **BASE** tag in html for for angular js and i have set `<base href='/'>`. So the scripts takes absolute path.

Comment: `<base href='/'>` will make cordova to fail and not to find the files