# how to remove / in from all the path like image src, script src, css href in angular 2 webpack

Tags: cordova, angular, webpack

i am following the webpack reference from angular.io site.

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/webpack.html

it is working fine, and the output html is below

```
    <body>
some others are here
<script src="/vendor.63cf4fc3fcc633a1c7bd.js"></script>
    </body>
```

problem is this path is not working in cordova android.

working path are ./ else remove the first / of src attribute

Can anyone help me to alter this src using webpack please,

so that the output path will be ,

```
 <script src="vendor.63cf4fc3fcc633a1c7bd.js"></script>
```

or

```
 <script src="./vendor.63cf4fc3fcc633a1c7bd.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's probably not Cordova's fault, as it would be odd for it to break the standard of reading resources in html.

It may instead by related to your `base href` that you probably set for angular's router. See the answer to [cordova script src takes relative path rather absolute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28297908/cordova-script-src-takes-relative-path-rather-absolute)